# Jquery checkbox function backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Quick question. Can anyone tell me why this function is working backwards? For example, when I check it, it unchecks all of my checkboxes and when I uncheck it, it checks all of checkboxes.

The function was working fine until I added the .click() method at the end. However I need this so that the boxes call the function when clicked. Any help is appreciated!

Jquery:

```
 $("#checkAll").click(function () {
 $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).click();
 });
```

HTML Master Checkbox:

```
<div id="masterButton">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" checked>Check/UnCheck All<br>
    </div>
```

HTML All other checkboxes:

```
<input id="bus0" type="checkbox" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to click all the checkboxes that are **not** checked the same as your primary checkbox. So just add a `!` and you're fine:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked).click();
});
```

Comment: So simple yet I've been stuck for an hour. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Gotta wait 4 more minutes, then I will!